# How to performance test websites using Gatling that are encrypted using Certbot?

Tags: gatling, certbot

**Aim**

to performance test a UI

**Method**

- Run [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) recorder
- Once the gatling recorder proxy has been started, configure this proxy in the webbrowser that will be used for the test
- Login to the UI
- Navigate to the website
- Save the recording

**Results**

When a http site is recorded, then it is recorded, but when an https site then gatling records nothing

**Discussion**

Gatling can record websites, but when these are encrypted then one could define the following:

HTTPS mode:

- self-signed certificate
- provided keystore

  - keystore file
  - keystore pasword
  - keystore type
- certificate authority

  - ca certificate
  - ca private key

How to record websites that are encrypted using Certbot?

[This topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/VI0MkEJGIj8) has been created in the Google user group.

Comment: @Tensibai improved?

Comment: Yep, far better :)

Comment: And now I can understand it act as a man in the middle proxy and provide and answer not using fallback to http (tomorrow) :)

Comment: Checking again, I still don't get why you can navigate to the UI through gatling recorder but not recording anything, don't you have some company management system breaking your browser configuration when you point it to gatling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible to switch https to http temporarly then gatling can record the clicks. When the recording was done, https was activated again and the test could be run against https as well. In summary, recording works if the site is http and running it works against https. Note that the recorder file contains http and this need to be changed to https.